# Unrar files via debian command line

Tags: debian, rar

The unrar command does not seem to work for some files. If I unrar the files with WinRar on Windows it works without a charge. These files are password encrypted and split into multiple files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the free or nonfree *unrar*?  (The free version is in package *unrar-free*, the nonfree version in package *unrar*.  Check which you have installed with `dpkg -l | grep unrar`.)

The *unrar-free* package won't handle some archives in the RAR 3.0 archive format.  You can try using the nonfree *unrar* package (install with `sudo apt-get install unrar`).

Alternatively, you can try using 7zip (install the *p7zip-full* and *p7zip-rar* packages), or you can grab the latest RAR binaries [direct from RARlabs](http://www.rarlabs.com/download.htm).  The official RARlabs version is a 40-day trial; see their site for [a pricelist](http://www.rarlab.com/shop2rarlab.php?prod=linux).

Comment: +1, also for the 7zip reference. But, I have had a couple of instances where 7zip had trouble opening a RAR file and unrar had to be used. I am still wondering about them -- did not bother to analyze too much.

Comment: @nik probably a similar problem.  RARlabs created the format and the latest RAR formats are closed-source.  open-source tools get to reverse engineer the formats and don't always get the details right.  IIRC, *unrar-free* is an old version of RARlabs' own code that was offered freely, but the license changed with newer versions that support the newer file formats.